# Getting geolocation on .net server request

Tags: .net, geolocation

I'm trying to set my server to return specific content based on whether or not a user is inside a predefined region. To do this I need the user's current geolocation.

Currently the geolocation is being retrieved using Javascript and HTML5 by receiving the geolocation and storing it as a cookie. This works to get location specific information after refreshing the page but not on the initial load.

A solution I'm currently doing is to AJAX all of the changed data onto the page if the geolocation has been changed, but that is undesirable compared to retrieving the correct data on the page load from the server.

Is there any way I could get the geolocation data from anywhere, such as on the request, if the user has already allowed permissions to access geolocation using a .NET server?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about what you're trying to achieve, but I have used [this](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/javascript/tutorial/) in the past and I could get the information required on page-load and did not require permissions.

Comment: Maybe you can use client's IP http://www.ipinfodb.com/ip_location_api_json.php

Comment: @Dura I'm getting the user's geolocation but I'm having to get it after the page has rendered, which means the client suffers from a "flicker" when the page is re-organised, and the information displayed has to be generated twice (once on page load, once on ajax call)